# multiple where statement in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to implement filter search result through ajax in laravel 5.4 Currently i am facing a problem with whereBetween when combined with other where statement.

I have an query statement as below:

```
    $query   = $this->hotel->query();
    $query   = $query->where(function ($query){
                    $query->orWhereBetween('min_price' , [500 , 1000]);
                    $query->orWhereBetween('min_price' , [5000 , 50000]);
                });
    $query   = $query->whereIn('internet', [1,2]);
    $query   = $query->whereIn('breakfast', [1,2]);
    $query   = $query->where('language', 'LIKE', '%'.'english'.'%');

    $hotel = $query->get();
    foreach($hotel as $h) {
        echo $h->id.'<br>';
    } exit();
```

The above query doesn't list the result of price between `500 to 100` and `5000 to 50000` There are two rows matching the conditions above but it return only single row.

**Database data**

```
id    min_price    internet    breakfast    language
4     876          2           2            english
5     40000        1           2            english
```

**Result:**
The above query result only id 4, but should return both ids 4 and 5.

I think I am missing something on line

```
$query   = $query->where(function ($query){
                    $query->orWhereBetween('min_price' , [500 , 1000]);
                    $query->orWhereBetween('min_price' , [5000 , 50000]);
                });
```

How can I achieve correct result? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure with your requirements but you may need to arrange your where conditions like

```
$query   = $query->orWhere(function ($q){ //assuming b/w is not mandatory
                    $q->whereBetween('min_price' , [500 , 1000]); // removed OR from here
                    $q->orWhereBetween('min_price' , [5000 , 50000]);
                });
```

Comment: any specific reason to remove OR ? removing OR condition will make it compusion to check the criteria even if that is not on filter

Comment: it will be mandatory for those betweens (b/w or b/w) .. if both b/w are not mandatory then use `orWhere`  . Added comment for the same in answer

Comment: both where are not mendatory

Comment: then use `orWhere` as main condition, updated my answer as well

Comment: please accept  as an answer to close the question, if you find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

Change your inner where clause variable name.

```
$query   = $query->where(function ($q){
                    $q->WhereBetween('min_price' , [500 , 1000]);
                    $q->orWhereBetween('min_price' , [5000 , 50000]);
                });
```